# Not understanding my python dilemma

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to finish up an assignment for a class "grade determination"

Write a program that will input 3 test scores.The program should determine and display their average.The program should then display the appropriate letter grade based on the average.The letter grade should be determined using a standard 10-point scale: (A = 90-100; B = 80-89.999; C = 70-79.999, etc.)

So far what I've been able to put together, (and it works averaging)

```
def main():  
    score1 = input("What is the first test score? ")
    score2 = input("What is the second test score? ")
    score3 = input("What is the third test score? ")
    scoreaverage = score1 + score2 + score3
score = (scoreaverage / 3)
    if score < 60:
        grade="F"
elif score < 70:
        grade="C"
elif score < 80:
        grade="B"
elif score < 90:
        grade="A"
else:
        print score, " is the student's grade average!"


main()
```

If I replace score with grade I get an error.

```
raceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in main
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'grade' referenced before assignment
```

So my question is how do I get the letter grade to print correctly?

Comment: Is this your complete code, indented exactly like this? I dont think so, because it wouldn't raise an UnboundLocalErorr for grade...

Comment: You should use 4 spaces and not a tab for indentation, otherwise the code indentation breaks when pasted on SO. The problem in your code is that the `print` is executed when `grade` wasn't defined.

Comment: @Joshua If one of these answers solved your problem, you should accept it by clocking the checkmark by the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
def main():  
    score1 = input("What is the first test score? ")
    score2 = input("What is the second test score? ")
    score3 = input("What is the third test score? ")
    scoreaverage = score1 + score2 + score3
    score = (scoreaverage / 3)
    if score < 60:
        grade="F"
    elif score < 70:
        grade="C"
    elif score < 80:
        grade="B"
    elif score < 90:
        grade="A"
    else:
        print score, " is the student's grade average!"

main()
```

This would be your indented code. Are you sure you get the error you are mentioning?
The following code would generate the error you are mentioning.

```
    print grade, " is the student's grade average!"
```

You can fix it this way:

```
def main():  
    score1 = input("What is the first test score? ")
    score2 = input("What is the second test score? ")
    score3 = input("What is the third test score? ")
    scoreaverage = score1 + score2 + score3
    score = (scoreaverage / 3)
    grade = 'Unknown'
    if score < 60:
        grade="F"
    elif score < 70:
        grade="C"
    elif score < 80:
        grade="B"
    elif score < 90:
        grade="A"

    print "%s is the student's grade average!" % grade

main()
```

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I meant to say that I'm trying to get the grade to print so it would be "The student averaged an B" or something along the lines of that

Comment: looks like you got what you were looking for. Checkout the fix

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO. As explained by others, your problem was accessing grade before assigning a value to it. Here is another suggestion for doing what you want to do: (see the comments)

```
#disregard next line if you are using Python 3.3
from __future__ import division

#use a list to store the scores
scores = []

#if you are using 2.7 replace input with raw_input
#use float() to convert the input to float
scores.append(float(input("First score? ")))
scores.append(float(input("Second score? ")))
scores.append(float(input("Third score? ")))

#More general way of calculating the average
score = sum(scores) / len(scores)

#You could use a dictionary for score-grade mapping
grades = {100: 'A', 90: 'A', 80: 'B',
          70: 'C', 60: 'D', 50: 'E',
          40: 'F', 30: 'F', 20: 'F',
          10: 'F', 0: 'F'}

#removes the remainder from the score
#to make use of the above dictionary
grade = grades[score - (score % 10)]

#Use string formatting when printing
print('grade: %s, score: %.2f' % (grade, score))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your grade comparisons are off by 10 points. You won't assign anything to grade if score is between 90 and 100. And a piece of advice for a newbie programmer: Use a debugger. You'd have discovered the problem in just a few minutes had you stepped through it.

Try:

```
if score < 60:
    grade="F"
elif score < 70:
    grade="D"
elif score < 80:
    grade="C"
elif score < 90:
    grade="B"
else:
    grade="A"
```